# Plot a 2D-map in Gnuplot of file containing non-equidistant X,Y,Z values

Tags: gnuplot, multiple-columns, surface

I have a file with 3 columns, which represent following data types:

```
X-value ---> $1: contains non-equidistant energy values

Y-value ---> $2: contains non-equidistant energy values

Z-value ---> $3: represents the intensity scale given in powers of E-2
```

The (x,y)-map shall represent a pair of energies given with a certain intensity (represented by the colour scale). There are regions in the rectangle where I do not have any data-points and there I would like Gnuplot to fill it with zero-intensity.
How can I do that?

Moreover I would like gnuplot to interpolate ONLY between actually existing points and not to invent an interpolation for regions where I actually have no data.

Basically I expect to obtain a couloured triangle (with the respective intensities) at the bottom and the rest of the rectangle (where no data points are contained) I want to have a "black" (zero-intensity) area (which is also going to be a triangle.
Please help me.

I have tried with `pm3d` with `dgrid3d` with several other things I have read all over the internet and in the gnuplot manual as well, but up to now the closest thing which I got was by doing:

```
set pm3d interpol 0.5,0.5 map

set pal def

set hiddend3d

splot "file_with_3_columns.txt" u 1:2:3 lc pal z
```

BUT here it fills the should-be-black regions with invented colours based on its interpolation....

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add a black triangle with `set object`:

```
max_x = 10 # max value x axis 
max_y = 10 # max value y axis
min_x = 0  # min value x axis
min_y = 0  # min value y axis

set object 1 polygon front from max_x,min_y,0 to max_x, max_y,0 to min_x,max_y,0 fillstyle solid noborder fillcolor rgb 'black'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer TomNap. I am aware of that, but I neither want to invent data, nor I want to cover faulty calculated data, I just want to understand how to explicitly manipulate the interpolation in Gnuplot. In the meantime I have started to add experimentally measured "zeros" to the  rectangular matrix thus to impose to perform a more credible interpolation.